# Время 00:00:00

Tags: процесс

На часах 00:00:00  переход  с 10 на 11 августа это время 10 числа или 11?

Comment: 1. http://habrahabr.ru/post/100741/
2. http://habrahabr.ru/post/146109/

Очень пользительно. Прошу ознакомиться.

Comment: У всего есть свое начало, так сказать....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

00:00:00 11 числа, а 23:59:59 10 числа

Comment: Неужели так много людей не знали об этом !?

Answer (score 1):

11 числа